# Unsuppored Swift Version Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode

I open an existing project it contains many errors, this image explains more the issue:

[image]

I execute "pod install" but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: you should try pod update.

Comment: What pods do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Change **Swift Language Version** to Swift 4 or higher, found in build settings.

Comment: It is set to 4, but the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

move to the build setting of the project and change the project to swift4 and also move to the pods and every pod you have to change the Swift language version that is Swift 4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCCwU.png)

Answer (score 0):

The message describes all the things itself. You can not convert `3.x` swift version into the latest one by using `Xcode 10.2.1`. You need to open this project in `Xcode 10.1` first then convert it into the `4.x` swift version.

Later you can open it in `10.2.1` version.

`pod install` will just install the `pods` with locked version of each library, of course it will not solve the issue.